# jquery mobile and javascript dialog not showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mobile

I have a php form with several checkboxes and radio buttons using jqueryMobile. When the user submits the form a javascript function is executed. This function basically checks wether any radio button has been pressed or not and warns the user that he/she has to check a minimum of one radio button. I tried a lot of things to show a simple alert dialog box but cannot seem to make it work in mobile devices. My android form basically shows nothing. Any ideas will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the form:

```
<form id="EnviarEnquesta">
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="<?php echo(_('SendSurvey')); ?>" onClick="doSomeChecks();" />
</form>
```

Here is the javascript function

```
function doSomeChecks(){

var formObj = document.getElementById("enviarEnquesta");
(...)
    if(counter == 0){
        /*display a jquery mobile alert type*/
    }else{ 
        /*just submit the form*/
        document.getElementById("enviarEnquesta").submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Element IDs are case sensitive in some browsers. Change the form id to match the one used in JavaScript (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Basic popup usage:using the **[open()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#method-open)** method:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Example Page</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <button id="openpopup">Open popup</button>
  </div>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic"> <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p> </div>
</div>


<script>
$(document).on("pagecreate","#page", function(){ 
    $("#openpopup").click(function(){
        var contador=0;
        if(contador == 0)
        $( "#popupBasic" ).popup( "open");      
        else alert("contador is not zero!");
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Dialogs are deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 and will be removed in 1.5.0. Consider popup (http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/). Also have a look at the SweetAlert library, which works pretty well with jqm: http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot make it work yet. I have the following div:  

`<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
  <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
</div>`

if I set a href link like this it works:  
<br/>
`<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>`

But inside the javascript function it does not work:

`if(contador == 0){
  
 $( "#popupBasic" ).popup("open");
}`

Any ideas?